# Spring Initializr Error in Intellij Idea and STS on mac os

Tags: spring, macos, intellij-idea, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have installed Intellij Idea on my macbook. When I going to create a Spring project using Spring Initializr and press "next" button, it prompts an alert window with the heading "Spring Initilizr Error", and with message body -

"Initialisation failed for 'https://start.spring.io' 
Please check URL, Network and Proxy settings
Error Message
Cannot download 'https://start.spring.io':
Status 403".

[image]

[image]

I have used https://start.spring.io as Spring Initializr url, which is being set by default in Intellij Idea. I have also tried the url changing as http://start.spring.io, but it also haven't worked too.

I have tried to use Spring Tool Suit (STS) to create Spring Initializr project and got this message: "IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://start.spring.io".

My network connection is ok and firewall is turned off too. If someone have already faced this issue, please help me with your overcoming steps. I am struggling too much with this problem and wasted enough time with it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like some proxy/certs issues.

Comment: I also think so

Comment: as a workaround, you can go to https://start.spring.io using your browser, select the dependencies there, and download the project ZIP at the end. Then import this ZIP file in STS using the "Import Existing Maven Project" wizard (from the "Import..." context menu).

Comment: @MartinLippert Thanks for your suggestion, but I am seeking for any solution so that I can overcome this issue and continue my tasks as like others, using my device.

Comment: As other have mentioned already `403` error is most likely a proxy / firewall preventing you to access the service. If you are in a corporate network, you may want to talk to your IP department about what kind of configuration might be needed to get past the firewall.

Comment: @Kris, I have found this 403 error in my personal device (mac os) at my home network. Can you please give me a hint or some link to identify and fix this?

Comment: Sorry, previous comment deleted. Spoke too soon. You are on a home network and a Mac. I vaguely remember other folks on macs reporting issue somewhat like yours and they had to mess around with some network configs. But I can't recall the details now. I'll look for it and post a link if I find it.

Comment: Found it... https://jira.spring.io/browse/STS-4413 but my memory is a bit faulty as this was an issue with making connections to local processes. So its likely something else. Maybe someone who actually has a Mac might have some better advise... I'm all out of ideas. Sorry :-(

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam, Are you using Java 11? I have found the same problem just after installing Java 11. I am also using a home network without any proxy or certs.

Comment: @iamcrypticcoder, nope. I have found the issue for Java 8. But it seems not related to java version.

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam I wonder it's totally networking ISP issue. I had to use proxy for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, that was also in my case. I was confused to mention this as it seems lol to blame ISP.

Answer (score 0):

press `Ctrl+Alt+S` and search for `proxy`. This will show you the proxies you have set for IntelliJ; try to remove or add any.

Remember spring website will block `tor`.